# C++ - grep path in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I am new to linux and I want to know how to get path which is in the following format - `/home/linux/sample/`?

I want to write a `c++` function which takes the path as input and returns true as if the path has `/home/linux/sample/`.

Example:

If the path is `/home/linux/sample/test.txt` should return `true`

If the path is `/home/linux/sample/dir` should return `true`

If the path is `/home/linux/user/test.txt` should return `false`

Can some one please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To write such a function you need only std::string:

```
string str ("There are two needles in this haystack.");
string str2 ("needle");

if (str.find(str2) != string::npos) {
//.. found.
}
```

If the algorithm will get more sophisticated than I would move to regular expressions.

Comment: that will just see if "needle" is  present anywhere in the string, how to check if the string starts with "needle"

Comment: the original question was " the path has /home/linux/sample/." in this case I would use regular expression. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/regular_expression_in_c_11_14?lang=en

Comment: so i just have to use 


`std::regex expr (" /home/linux/sample/(.*)");
  if (std::regex_match (path.begin(), path.end(), expr)) { .... }'`

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any compiler around me. It should'nt be hard its a basic stuff. For sure you are on the good way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to check if a string is the prefix of another one. In that case, you can rely on `std::equal` from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::string prefix = "/home/linux/sample/";
std::string path0 = "/home/linux/sample/test.txt";
if(std::equal(prefix.begin(), prefix.end(), path0.begin())) {
...
}
```

The `/` at the end of `prefix` is important!